# Quiero llevar todos los nombres de 3 tablas a 3 select pero solo me lleva 2 tablas laravel

Tags: laravel

Quiero llevar los nombres de las tablas `actividades`, `gerencia` y `unidad` pero solo me esta llevando los 2 primeros; en el `return` el de actividades no me lo envía si lo coloco de ultimo:

```
public static function organizar_get(Request $request) {
    $actividades=actividades::all()->pluck('ao','id');
    $gerencia=gerencia::all()->pluck('ga','id');
    $unidad=unidades::all()->pluck('unidad','id');

    return return \View::make('organizar',compact('gerencia'),compact('unidad',compact('actividades')));
}
```

Este es el error que me tira:

> Undefined variable: actividades (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-organizar.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-organizar.blade.php)

Comment: Cuando realizas el `return` esta dos veces la palabra reservada `return`. Por otra parte no debes colocar `compact` por cada variable que vas a pasar a la vista `return \View::make('organizar', compact('gerencia', 'unidad', 'actividades'));` haz la prueba y confirmas.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que estás haciendo un **compact anidado**

```
return \View::make('organizar',compact('gerencia'),compact('unidad',compact('actividades')));
```

Cuando debería de ser:

```
return \View::make('organizar',compact('gerencia'),compact('unidad'),compact('actividades'));
```

También puedes intentar pasar esa información mediante un arreglo:

```
public static function organizar_get(Request $request) {
    $actividades=actividades::all()->pluck('ao','id');
    $gerencia=gerencia::all()->pluck('ga','id');
    $unidad=unidades::all()->pluck('unidad','id');

   return \View::make('organizar',[
     'actividades'=>$actividades,
     'gerencia'=>$gerencia,
     'unidad'=>$unidad
    ]);
```

}

Comment: de hecho no es correcto y funcional usar tantos compact cuando en uno solo se pueden mandar todos los valores

Comment: Concuerdo. Aún así puede ser remplazado con uno solo o simplemente mandar un arreglo. Y ambos casos serian validos.

Comment: rechacé la edición que propusiste a la pregunta, la idea es dejarla como esta y darle la solución en esta zona, sino estas haciendo mal uso por que se pierde el sentido de la misma al borrar el error, por favor evita hacer esto

Answer (score 1):

Puedes enviar tus valores utilizando un solo Compact de la siguiente manera

```
return view('organizar', compact('gerencia', 'unidad', 'actividades'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando realizas el `return` esta dos veces la palabra reservada `return`.

Por otra parte no debes colocar `compact` por cada variable que vas a pasar a la vista. En tu caso tendrias que colocar:

```
return \View::make('organizar', compact('gerencia', 'unidad', 'actividades'));
```